# Google Sheets query pivot multiple values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, pivot-table

I am trying to use a Query to replicate the behaviour pictured below. I have a pivot table with two values (as rows) displaying a job name and it's status. This works fine with the built-in pivot table.

Sample Data:
[image: Sample data]

Resulting pivot table:
[image: Pivot table]

I've then tried to recreate this using the following Query formula:

=QUERY(A1:D6, " select C, max(A), max(D) GROUP BY C PIVOT B Order by C  ")

This gives me the result below. This is as close as I've managed to get to replicating the original pivot table.

[image: Query]

### Edit

The main part of this question has been solved below but I'm wondering how to extend this out if I had more columns of data that I then wanted to display in the same way. Below I have added an additional column 'Other'.

New data:
[image: New data]

New desired result:
[image]

Comment: Is there any issue with the pivot table? I think that's a better approach rather than using a query, due to the calculated columns with combined data, I wouldn't do it, but maybe your use case requires it

Comment: sadly i need a little more flexibility than pivot tables seem to offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`=Index({"",Transpose(Unique(Filter(B2:B,B2:B<>"")));Flatten({Sort(Unique(C2:C)),IFError(Unique(C2:C)/0)}),IFNA(VLookup(Transpose(Unique(Filter(B2:B,B2:B<>"")))&Flatten({Text(Sort(Unique(C2:C)),"hh:mm"),Text(Sort(Unique(C2:C)),"hh:mm")&".1"}),{Flatten({B2:B&Text(C2:C,"hh:mm"),B2:B&Text(C2:C,"hh:mm")&".1"}),Flatten({A2:A,D2:D})},2,0))})`

[image]

Comment: Interesting! Can confirm that this does indeed work. Will have to take some time to digest what is going on here now. Thanks

Comment: Curious to know if there is a way to do this with more columns of data, like in my edit to the original post?

Comment: @herman yes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71080343/5632629