# Google Sheets pivot data with multiple values

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table, vlookup, flatten, google-query-language

I'm trying to display sample data as follows. I'm able to do this using pivot tables and multiple values with no problem but would like to find a way using either Query or some other method. This problem was partly solved using the formula below but does not include the 'Other' column.

```
=Index({"",Transpose(Unique(Filter(B2:B,B2:B<>"")));Flatten({Sort(Unique(C2:C)),IFError(Unique(C2:C)/0)}),IFNA(VLookup(Transpose(Unique(Filter(B2:B,B2:B<>"")))&Flatten({Text(Sort(Unique(C2:C)),"hh:mm"),Text(Sort(Unique(C2:C)),"hh:mm")&".1"}),{Flatten({B2:B&Text(C2:C,"hh:mm"),B2:B&Text(C2:C,"hh:mm")&".1"}),Flatten({A2:A,D2:D})},2,0))})
```

Sample data:
[image]

Desired result:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"", TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B, B2:B<>""))); 
 FLATTEN({SORT(UNIQUE(C2:C)), IFERROR(TEXT(UNIQUE(C2:C), {"@", "@"})/0)}), 
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B, B2:B<>"")))&FLATTEN({TEXT(SORT(UNIQUE(C2:C)), "hh:mm"), 
 TEXT(SORT(Unique(C2:C)), "hh:mm")&{".1", ".2"}}), {FLATTEN({B2:B&TEXT(C2:C, "hh:mm"), 
 B2:B&TEXT(C2:C, "hh:mm")&{".1", ".2"}}), FLATTEN({A2:A, D2:D, E2:E})}, 2, ))})
```

[image]